# $\int_c 3y dx +5x dy + \frac{2x+3}{z^2} dz$ for the intersection between two surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

For the closed curve, $c = \{(x,y,z) \vert x^2 + y^2 - z^2 =0\} \cap \{(x,y,z) \vert (x-1)^2 + y^2 =4\}$

Find the $\int_c 3y dx +5x dy + \frac{2x+3}{x^2 + y^2} dz$

First I focused the surface $\{(x,y,z) \vert x^2 + y^2 - z^2 =0\}$ and tried to simplify like the $\int_c 3y dx +5x dy + \frac{2x+3}{z^2} dz$.

Next step is parameterizing the boundary surface $X(r,\theta)= (1+rcos\theta, rsin\theta, \pm\sqrt{1+r^2 + 2rcos\theta})$ for $0\leq r \leq 2, 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

But the problem happened there are two curves. To applying the Stoke's thm, Which curve do I choose? Plus Is there are another methods without stokes thm? It is too complicated to solve by the Stokes thm. Help me.

Comment: $x^2+y^2 = z^2$ represents two cones, one above $z = 0$ and one below. $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 4$ is a cylinder that intersects both cones. So there are two closed curves of intersection. Which one are you trying to find the line integral over?

Comment: @MathLover, Thanks for comment. My question is which curve have to choose between two of them.

Comment: the question should have stated that. there is no way for us to know which curve without question stating it. Even the orientation should have been given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Given there are two intersection curves, the question should have stated which intersection curve. It is a different matter that the line integral over either curve is same.* It should have also stated orientation. Say we are interested in evaluating line integral over the intersection curve above $z = 0$ in anticlockwise direction. An easier approach in this case is direct line integral over the closed curve instead of applying Stokes' theorem. Applying Stokes' theorem would require you to consider a surface that does not cross z-axis.

At the intersection, $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 4 \implies x^2 + y^2 = 3 + 2x = z^2$

Parametrizing the intersection curve as $r (t) = (1 + 2 \cos t, 2 \sin t, \sqrt{5+4 \cos t}), 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$

$r'(t) = (- 2 \sin t, 2 \cos t, - \frac{2 \sin t}{\sqrt{5 + 4 \cos t}})$

$\vec F = (3y, 5x, \frac{2x+3}{x^2+y^2}) = (6 \sin t, 5 + 10 \cos t, 1)$

Then evaluate $ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \vec F \cdot r'(t) ~ dt$ and that gets an answer of $8 \pi$. The work can be simplified using the fact that integral of $\cos t$ and $\cos 2t$ over $(0, 2\pi)$ evaluates to zero.

Comment: Haha yes. When I re-checked this question in my book, It doesn't give any informations for the curve. It looks like a defected question itself. Any way your answer is right. Its answer was $8\pi$

Comment: @kechanglee unfortunately we find many such questions in books that give inadequate info.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0$ represents a cone with axis along the $z$ axis, and $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 4 $ is a right circular cylinder with axis parallel to the $z$ axis and passing through $(1, 0)$ and a radius of $2$.

Let $x = 1 + 2 \cos \theta , y = 2 \sin \theta $, then this point lies on the cylinder, the intersection with the cone results in

$z^2 = x^2 + y^2 = 5 + 4 \cos \theta $

Take $z$ to be positive, then $z = \sqrt{ 5 + 4 \cos \theta } $

Differentials:

$dx = -2 \sin \theta d\theta $

$dy = 2 \cos \theta d\theta $

$dz = \dfrac{- 2 \sin \theta d \theta }{ \sqrt{5 + 4 \cos \theta }} $

$\displaystyle \int_C 3 y dx + 5 x dy + \dfrac{2x+3}{x^2 + y^2} dz $

Becomes

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2 \pi} (-6 \sin^2 \theta + 10(1 + 2 \cos \theta) \cos \theta + \dfrac{ 2(1 + 2 \cos \theta) + 3 }{5 + 4 \cos \theta } \dfrac{- 2 \sin \theta}{ \sqrt{5 + 4 \cos \theta }}) d\theta $

which simplifies to

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2 \pi} (-12 \sin^2 \theta + 20 \cos^2 \theta + 10 \cos \theta + \dfrac{- 2 \sin \theta}{ \sqrt{5 + 4 \cos \theta }}) d\theta = \dfrac{1}{2} (-12 + 20)(2 \pi) = \boxed{8 \pi}$